Who has the right to examine a will?
If a person is notified that they are named in a will and there is an asset they will inherit, would that person then have the right to examine the will if it's not already public information? The decedent was a resident of Delaware if it's state specific.

By § 2516 (d) of Title 12: Decedents’ Estates and Fiduciary Relations:

Upon receipt of notice of the death of the testator or testatrix or by order of the court, the Register shall open the will and place the will in its pending file to await probate. While awaiting probate the will may be reviewed by any person entitled to offer it for probate, authorized by court order or named in the will as a beneficiary, trustee or guardian. Copies of the will shall be given to the executor, executrix, beneficiary, trustee, guardian, at their request or upon court order. The person or party making the request shall be responsible for reasonable copying charges. Except as provided herein, no other person is permitted to receive a copy of a will. (Emphasis mine)


It also bears noting that once the probate case is opened, the will is generally a matter of public record.
